# Google translate setcookie is not working

Tags: php, google-translate

I want to change default language of google translate and for that I have used

```
  unset($_COOKIE['googtrans']);
  setcookie("googtrans","/en/es", time()+3600, "/");
```

for changing into SPANISH language. But this isn't working. Other code used is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: true}, 
        'google_translate_element'
    );  
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

order of the code is same as given
I have also tried unsetting the cookie using

```
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600,'/');
```

But this is also not working.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Will the cookie not be set? Please check your `php_error_log` for errors, warnings & notices. Maybe there is some output before `setcookie` call, so that it does not work. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/3647441

Comment: yes cookie is not getting set I have printed value of cookie and it does not exist after unsetting, even after setting it does not exist. I have checked in exception.log and system.log there is no such error.

Comment: It is working correct on local but not converting to specific language on server. I am using magento, is that the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It worked after giving domain parameter(while setting cookie)

```
setcookie("googtrans","/en/es", time()+3600, "/",'.domain.com');
```

And when unsetting cookie

```
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600,'/','');
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600,'/','.domain.com');
```